# Repeating time windows in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'd like to insert time windows repeatedly in a column, like this:

```
10:00-10:20
10:20-10:40
10:40-11:00
11:00-11:20
11:20-11:40
12:00-12:20
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to do it via formula? Via GAS? Using the API? What have you tried already

Answer (score 0):

Put data in cells:

1. B1 = 10:00 (start time)
2. B2 = 12:20 (end time)
3. B3 = 20 (interval in    minutes)

Here's single arrayFormula, that will generate your column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(B1+B3*1/24/60*(row(OFFSET(B8,,,(B2-B1)/(B3*1/24/60)))-row(B7)-1),"HH:MM")&"-"&TEXT(B1+B3*1/24/60*(row(OFFSET(B8,,,(B2-B1)/(B3*1/24/60)))-row(B7)),"HH:MM"))
```

---

**Explanations**

Look at [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KyHZhZef2JbfpgiBE61WKlHaLOs8XkdO72-_EWXeL-0/edit#gid=787300444) to explore more about this formula. Pay attention on some details:

- any kind of logical sequence could be done with help of series 1,2,3... Formula like `=ARRAYFORMULA(row(OFFSET(B8,,,7))-row(B7))` gives us column from 1 to 7.
- Time treated like numbers in sheets: 1 day is `1`, 1 hour is `1/24`, 1 minute is `1/24/60` and so on
- Time can't be properly converted into text as it's number. So you have to use `text(time, "HH:MM")` formula to convert time into text.

Answer (score 0):

This will repeat your time window. The formula assumes the time range is in A2:A6.
The 3 in the formula is the number of repeats (change to you need). You might want
to consider placing A2:A6 on another sheet and referencing it in the formula.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",  ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(transpose(rept(join(",",A2:A6)&",",3)),",")&",")), ","))
```